# What are the different Kingdoms present in the Witcher TV series?

Tags: the-witcher

What are the different Kingdoms present in the Witcher TV series? We see a map of the Kingdoms in season 3 finale, but it is not very clear. Do we have an official map of the different Kingdoms of the continent?

Comment: The short answer is that a few maps were made (not by the author himself) and even published with the books, but there isn't an official map of The Witcher's world, because the author wants the freedom to modify its geography if needs be. https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/World_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of maps online, as mentioned in a comment you can find several in the [Witcher wiki](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/World_map). This one from [Reddit](https://i.redd.it/k67cyrkbf8741.png) is pretty clear with different colors for different countries. It shows the borders of the Kingdoms around the point when Ciri was born.

The main Kingdoms appearing in the TV series so far up to season 3 are:

- *Cintra* ruled by Queen Calanthe.
- *Nilfgaard Empire* ruled by Emperor Emhyr var Emreis.
- *Redania*, ruled by King Vizimir II.
- *Temeria*, ruled by King Foltest.
- *Aedirn*, ruled by Demavend III.
- *Skellige*, ruled by Eist Tuirseach (among others, Eist is appearing in season 1)

The elves in exile also speak of Dol Blathanna, a former elven Kingdom which in the books were located between Aedirn and Kaedwen. In the TV series they spin a separate non-canonical story with the elven Kingdom previously located in Cintra and claim that the elves were driven away from there. The Scoia'tael ("squirrels") guerilla army consists mainly of elves.

Basically the Continent has these powerful factions:

- The Cintra and Skellige alliance, formed by Calanthe and Eist Tuirseach.
- The Nilfgaard Empire, allied with Scoia'tael.
- The Northern Kingdoms, a military alliance mainly formed by Redania, Temeria, Aedirn, Kaedwen, Lyria and Rivia (plus some minor Kingdoms like Sodden, Verden, Cidaris).
- Kovir and Poviss (not yet appearing in the TV series), forming a powerful merchant league similar to the medieval Hansa.

Comment: We also had Sodden, Brokilon in the seasons do they fall under any kingdom

Comment: @codeczar Yes as mentioned in the Northern Kingdoms faction. Sodden is a minor Kingdom squeezed in between Cintra, Temeria and Nilfgaard. In the books I think they end up a vassal under Temeria after the battle of Sodden Hill, something like that. That battle happens "off camera" in the books, but it is often spoken of.

Comment: @codeczar As for, Brokilon isn't a Kingdom, just a forest wilderness inhabited by dryads, who aren't numerous enough to be a faction of their own. They fight guerilla warfare against surrounding settlements.